# Keep $_GET['p'] when form method get is submitted

Tags: php, html, forms

When I submit a form with method get, the get from form will erase previous `?p=page1&title=food`.
My url looks like `localhost/test/index.php?p=page1&title=0`

```
<form action="" method="get">
<input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

After I submit the form it will replace `localhost/test/index.php?p=page1&title=0` with `localhost/test/index.php?q=example` I would like `q` to be added to the existing url with `&`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try with hidden fields to send values again

```
<form action="" method="get">
<input type="hidden" name="p" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['p'])) echo $_GET['p'];?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="title" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['title'])) echo $_GET['title'];?>" />
<input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can also do

```
<form action="?p=<?php echo $_GET[p];?>" method="get">
<input type="hidden" name="title" value="<?php echo $_GET['title'];?>" />
<input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: the idea using this way is that you can still use this stuff even if you have a post method for you form, to keep the get attributes :-)